# Swap/exchange array keys php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Lets say I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 18208021789
    [1] => Ziggo-Humax iHDR5050C
    [2] => 191.90
    [4] => Something
    [5] => foo bar
}
```

And I want to change replace the place of [1] with [5], so as result I should have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 18208021789
    [1] => foo bar
    [2] => 191.90
    [4] => Something
    [5] => Ziggo-Humax iHDR5050C
}
```

How can I achieve this with PHP?

Answer (score 2):

```
$tmp=$arr[1];
$arr[1]=$arr[5];
$arr[5]=$tmp;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list($arr[1], $arr[5]) = array($arr[5], $arr[1]);
```

Read more about [list](http://php.net/list). Also, `list` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmp = $array[1];
$array[1] = $array[5];
$array[5] = $tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function. Just copy it :D

```
 function swapPos(&$arr, $pos1, $pos2){
      $keys = array_keys($arr);
      $vals = array_values($arr);
      $key1 = array_search($pos1, $keys);
      $key2 = array_search($pos2, $keys);

      $tmp = $keys[$key1];
      $keys[$key1] = $keys[$key2];
      $keys[$key2] = $tmp;

      $tmp = $vals[$key1];
      $vals[$key1] = $vals[$key2];
      $vals[$key2] = $tmp;

      $arr = array_combine($keys, $vals);
    }
```